# I couldn't achieve throttle effect in 'mouseover' addEventListener. 'e' is coming as undefined in logMousePosition function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Here below I have attached my code. please anyone guide me If I made any error in my code. give explanation on what is the issue here ?

I have worked in React js setState and I couldn't find any mistakes in my code. hard to understand  what is the problem here ?

Thanks.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';

function HookMouse(props) {

    const [x, setX] = useState(0)
    const [y, setY] = useState(0)

    const logMousePosition = e => {
        console.log("Event",e)
        
        setX(e.clientX)
        setY(e.clientY)
    }

    const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
        console.log(fn,delay)
        let shouldPause = false;
        return function() {
            console.log("Function",fn)
            if(shouldPause) return;
            fn();
            shouldPause = true;
            setTimeout(()=>{
                shouldPause = false;
            },delay)

        }
    }

    const betterFunc = throttle(logMousePosition,250);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect Called')
       
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', betterFunc)


        //cleanup code return function
        //If don't return it won't remove subscribers, timers, eventhandlers
        return () => {
            console.log('Component Unmounted')
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', betterFunc)

        }
    }, []) //empty array block for just initial render after that it will not render again and again
    
    return (
        <div>
            Hooks X - {x} Y - {y}
        </div>
    );
}

export default HookMouse;
```

Comment: You call `fn()` without passing a parameter, so of course `e` is `undefined`.

Comment: Add a parameter to the function you returned and use it inside `fn()`